# Play application.conf database setup?

Tags: playframework

How am i meant to setup a db in play?

Let's say i have this (from the play documentation):

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/db-file"
```

Where do i put it in application.conf?

Presumably I put it in a db { } thing, but the two (commented-out) db in the sample application.conf both have different names - one is `db`, the other is `play.db`, what do i put as the name?

And does it matter what i call the name - can i call it `mickey`, or would it have to be `mickey.db` and what does it matter what i call the name anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put them where the commented-out examples were.

If you have more than one connection you need to assign them names.

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/db-file1"

db.mickey.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.mickey.url="jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/db-file2"

db.secret.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.secret.url="jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/db-file3"
```

then, in your app you connect to them by:

```
val conn = db.getConnection() //default
val connMickey = DB.getConnection("mickey") //mickey
val connSecret = DB.getConnection("secret") //secret
```